# Definition of Nationalism/Nationalist/Nationalistic

Tags: meaning

I recently got into discussion with someone about the definition of these words:

- Nationalist
- Nationalism

From the onset I used the Oxford Dictionary as my go-to for saying 'I am a Nationalist, in that I *advocate political independence for a country*'. 
However the other person seemed to have a different idea of what a Nationalist was. This got us looking at Nationalism's definition and so on.
So now I have a range of questions ...
Oxford Dictionary shows the definition for Nationalist like so:

> 1. A person who advocates political independence for a country.
>
>    1.1 A person with strong patriotic feelings, especially one who believes in the superiority of their country over others.

The problem here is that by the definition on the first line (Is this the "Primary" definition? Is there such a thing as a "Primary", "Secondary" etc .. definition?), I would call myself a Nationalist, but by the definition at 1.1 I would not. Reason being that while I might think of myself as being patriotic I would not use a term like 'strongly' as I find it too subjective, and then the 'superiority of their country over others' part is not clear to me - is this saying 'superiority of their country over **all** others' or 'over **any** others' (I assumed the latter)?

And then if I look at the definition of Nationalism it gets me confused again.

> 1. Patriotic feeling, principles, or efforts.
>
>    1.1 An extreme form of patriotism marked by a feeling of superiority over other countries.
>      1.2 Advocacy of political independence for a particular country.

Here the "primary" definition of Nationalist has been placed at position 1.2 for Nationalism, while the 1.1 definition of Nationalist has retained it's place in the definition of Nationalism.

So can I call myself a Nationalist if 
a) I 'advocate political independence for a country', but 
b) my sense of patriotism is not 'marked by a feeling of superiority over other countries'?

Comment: The senses should be listed in order of frequency of usage (except in historical dictionaries like OED, where they're listed in order of first appearance). However, if you check in M-W, you'll see that they list the senses in a different order. When polysemes are involved (and that's usually the case), it's essential to define terms before you start your discussion.

Comment: These terms are highly charged, politically, and will mean different things in different political environments.  And the three terms all refer to the same concepts, but a given term may be adopted by a particular political movement and acquire more implications as a result.  But these implications would not generally carry outside of the given political environment.

Comment: You can, but there will always be people who either genuinely don't appreciate the distinctions, or who regard themselves as politically opposed and willing to use the term to paint you in a black light. A new, and accepted, term would be very useful.

Comment: If your country is already independent, then you can't be a nationalist in the first sense (desiring independence for your country). If you're a nationalist in a country that's already independent then you must be a nationalist in the second sense (patriotic to the point of denigrating people from other countries).

Comment: @ThePhoton - There is the sense of arguing for your country to implement policies that are "self-serving", even if at the expense of other countries and  cultures.  This stance can be taken even if the person does not (publicly) profess a belief in his own nation's or culture's superiority.

Comment: @HotLicks, Yes, it would have been more accurate to say, if your country is already independent, and you declare yourself a nationalist, *other people will assume you mean it* in the 2nd sense.

Comment: @ThePhoton What if ones country is independent but there are threats, political or otherwise, to it's independence. Cannot one still be a Nationalist in the first sense, in that you are continuing to advocate for policies which ensure your country's continued independence?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for your reply. In looking at the MW definition there is again the first overarching sense, which I affiliate with, but then there is that 1c) sense which starts off with 'exalting one nation above all others...' which I do not affiliate with. How to reconcile this? Also how does one know what sort of ordering a dictionary has?

Comment: @zetheroo, yes, that would work too.

Comment: (1) You **must** accept the dictionary rulings above your own opinions unless you are at say Professor Lawler's level. Asking the question you do here shows that, like the vast majority of us, you aren't. Dictionaries such as OED, ODO, AHD, Collins, M-W, CED invest heavily in research and analysis, so are far more likely to have the correct views. (2) Where dictionary listings conflict, it's clear that the issue is not clear-cut. Findings based on different pieces of research are rarely in exact agreement. One must accept that there is validity in different views. And that others often won't.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I do accept the that the definitions are legitimate, but what confuses me is that there seems to be a hierarchy of sorts in the way of numbering given to senses. For MW on Nationalism there is 1, 1c and 2. Is 1c one variant of 1 or is it the complete explanation of 1? Is it saying that Nationalism is 'loyalty and devotion to a nation' coupled with 'exalting one nation above all others', or is Nationalism 'loyalty and devotion to a nation' with or without 'exalting one nation above all others'? Because someone can be loyal and devoted to their nation without the bit in 1c.

Comment: Dictionaries should spell out the way they order senses. Have you checked? In the days of printed volumes, there were prefaces explaining layout. Nowadays, you may even need to contact individual companies.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have now written to both OED and MW to seek clarification. I was able to find something from MW about the layout schema of their definitions, but not from OED. I hope they both write me back. The guy I was discussing this with also got really stuck on the example sentence given which referred to 'right-wing nationalism' - he called this 'the context' of the definition and claimed that since I was right-wing therefore I was a Nationalist. This bewildered me - that a single example sentence could somehow become the definition in and of itself. :/

Comment: @zetheroo Impossible to say for certain without seeing the full quote, but while "_right-wing nationalism_" _could_ be in contrast to "_left-wing nationalism_" (e.g. the Nazis – aka National Socialism – were in part socialist, supporting nationalisation of some industries), _I suspect_ it is more likely to be using "_right wing_" as a synonym for _extreme_ (as in "_far-right_ nationalism").

Comment: @TripeHound, my understanding of the 'example sentences' is just to show in what context's the word sense *can* be used, not to suggest that the contexts are in an of themselves the definition, nor that they are *all* the ways in which the sense can be used. I also asked then how he reconciles his argument when there are plenty of examples of left-wing nationalism, to which he replied that there was no such thing.

Comment: The ambiguousness of terms sadly pervades a lot of arguments. People take as gospel the definitions they think are the only ones / the definitions they were once taught / the definitions they think should be the ones used, and get into bunfights with those holding conflicting views. The only people who are correct are the ones who have checked in various different respected reference works and realise that, if orders of listings differ, or if they are using a 'secondary' sense,  they must specify which sense they are choosing to use.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, that last thing you said is what I thought I had done - Referred to myself as a Nationalist based on one of the definitions of the word - 'advocate political independence for a country'. Was this incorrect? The more I look at the etymology of the word the more I find it's roots foreign to the concept of 'An extreme form of patriotism marked by a feeling of superiority over other countries.' It seems there are other words for that, like 'chauvinism' perhaps. So was my use of the word Nationalist wrong? I really want to know.

Comment: If (1) you're not bound by a University etc style guide, and (2) you've used a dictionary definition given (without a caveat like 'rare', 'obsolete', 'slang' ...) by a reputable dictionary, and taken care to point out which definition and which authority you're using for the next few minutes (this, as said, necessary especially when different dictionaries rank senses in different orders of 'primeness'), you've been totally correct. Anyone dismissing your selected usage is best avoided. / The etymology of a term is irrelevant here; modern usage drives acceptability. Look at 'anti-semitism'.